# Is the series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^k(\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k})$ convergent or divergent?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

This is quite infuriating. Just when I feel like I'm grasping this whole series konverging/diverging tests-notion, this one pops up. Here is what I did:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|(-1)^k(\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k})|=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k})=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt{k}}\leq\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}=\text{Div.}$$

So the series is not absolutely convergent. So this test didin't give me anything.

For Leibniz test, that states that if $\{a_k\}^{\infty}_{k=1}$ is a decreasing sequence of positive numbers with limit equal to zero, then the alternating series $\sum(-1)^{k-1}a_k$ is convergent.

However, $a_k=\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k}$ is unfortunately increasing.

Comment: Saying something is *less* than a divergent series doesn't help; you need to say $\sum{1\over\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt k}\ge{1\over2}\sum{1\over\sqrt{k+1}}$ (to show the series is not absolutely convergent).

Comment: Note also, $\sum_{k=1}^N(\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt k)=\sqrt{N+1}-1\to\infty$ as $N\to\infty$.

Comment: Because it telescopes right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 5):

I'm pretty sure $$a_{k}=\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt{k}}$$
Is decreasing. (Note that the denominator is increasing...)

Which means your series is convergent (By Leibniz's Rule, as you observed).

Comment: Funny how blind one can be sometimes. For some reason, I drew $a_k=\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt{k}$ and not it's conjugate. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The series converges.Note that$$\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt{k}}$$ Since $\frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt{k}}$ is positive,  decreasing, and converges to zero$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt{k}}$$satisfies all the conditions of a convergent alternating series.